# Use FORD documentation parser with Fortran Language Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, comments, documentation, intellisense

I am recreating a new Fortran90 environment using vscode with extensions (formatter, modern fortran, fortls & FORD documentation generator). I would like to use fortls features fully and easily document my code using FORD style. In the [Fortran Language Server Github](https://github.com/hansec/fortran-language-server), the following feature is specified :

> Documentation parsing (Doxygen and FORD styles)

FORD is installed and working well independently but I dont see any interaction with fortls and its vscode extension.
I tried to write some FORD comments but I don't see anything special:

```
subroutine example(i)
    !! This is a subroutine description
    !!
    !! I created this subroutine to test ford documentation parsing by fortls
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: i
    !! Integer to be printed
    print*, i
    !! Prints i
  end subroutine example
```

Does anyone know what this feature really does and how to use it properly?
What I mean is what does this feature bring to the basic operation of FORD?

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail *exactly* what you did? Best would be to give a short example of how you tried to generate the documentation.

Comment: The two tools are working independently but my question is : is there some feature (as indicated by fordls) allowing interaction between them? I wrote a documentation test to see if the extension is bringing something to the doc process but I don't see anything (see edit)

Comment: The language server [`fortls`](https://gnikit.github.io/fortls) is capable of parsing and displaying the docstrings of functions/subroutines and variables in hover messages, signature help messages and autocompletion results. That's what that statement means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, what that statement means is that the language server is able to parse and display the FORD documentation of functions, subroutines, module procedures and variables while hovering, completing argument lists of functions, subroutines and methods and while using autocompletions. This is inline with the language servers for other programming languages (C, C++, Python, Javascript, Typescript, etc.).

It does not mean that you are able to run FORD or Doxygen through the language server

Comment: Oh okay thank you ! I actually didn't see it the right way.

Comment: The document parser in fortls is not perfect so it might fail assigning the correct documentation at times, and it doesn't understand config files for Doxygen and FORD. If you have recommendations or any ideas feel free to start a Discussion either on GitHub https://github.com/gnikit/fortls/discussions or in Fortran-lang: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/